# Get Request Page in Workflow

Tags: 2010, workflow

I have a Workflow with the following condition:

```
if CurrentItem:Field1 is empty
Update Item in CurrentItem.
```

The update simply overwrites the Field1 with a value if it's empty. 
The problem is that this triggers on two events: on new item creation, and on update item. These two events are triggered from two different pages.

How can I specify in Workflow, that I want to trigger it only on item creation? I tried to expand the "if" but I cannot find a way to tell it from which page am I calling the Workflow from.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could for example add a yes/no field to your list, and on the end of your workflow update the field to "Yes" if its equals "No". Then add an IF statement before your CurrentItem:Field1 checking if your yes/no field equals "No". That way it will only trigger once, at item creation. Just make sure you don't add the field to any forms so users can change it back.